# Enable PK based filtering in Django Graphene Relay while retaining Global IDs

Tags: python, django, graphql, relay, graphene-python

## Problem

I am using django-graphene with Relay on our GraphQL Server. The implementation imposes a [Global ID requirement](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm) in the `graphene.relay.Node` class that **overrides and hides Django's ID field**.

As a result, I can query like this:

```
{
    allBatches(id:"QmF0Y2hOb2RlOjE=") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        pk
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And get this response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allBatches": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "QmF0Y2hOb2RlOjE=",
            "pk": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, what I lose is the ability to filter by the original ID (or PK) field of the Object itself:

```
{
    allBatches(id:1) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        pk
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In fact, I **simply cannot filter objects by ID**. 
I can think of two possible work-arounds to this:
1. Prevent django-graphene-relay from hijacking and shadowing the `id` field, perhaps force it to use a different field name such as `gid`
2. Find a way to include `pk` as a special field that is available both as a property and in filter

## Solution 1

I have made no progress on 1 since it appears as though `django-graphene` (and perhaps the relay standard) imposes a limitation that this field be called `id`. I see that `id` has been used as a Magic String in multiple places and there does not appear to be a standard way to change the field name.

## Solution 2

On 2, I can get the property to work with a `Mixin` like this:

```
class PKMixin(object):
    pk = graphene.Field(type=graphene.Int, source='pk')
```

However, I am unable to get the filtering via `django-filter` to work, since the `FilterSet` does not have the field `pk` declared and breaks with the following error

> 'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet:
>   pk

### Update on 2

I tried the following:

```
class PKFilteringNode(Node):

    @classmethod
    def get_node_from_global_id(cls, info, global_id, only_type=None):
        # So long as only_type is set; if we detect that the global_id is a pk and not a global ID;
        # then coerce it to be a proper global ID before fetching
        if only_type:
            try:
                int(global_id)
                global_id = cls.to_global_id(only_type._meta.name, global_id)
                return super(PKFilteringNode, cls).get_node_from_global_id(info, global_id, only_type)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return super(PKFilteringNode, cls).get_node_from_global_id(info, global_id, only_type)
```

And now I can get GraphQL to do this:

```
{
  batchA: batch(id: "QmF0Y2hOb2RlOjE=") {
    id
    name
  }
  batchB: batch(id: 1) {
    id
    name
  }
}
{
  "data": {
    "batchA": {
      "id": "QmF0Y2hOb2RlOjE=",
      "name": "Default Batch"
    },
    "batchB": {
      "id": "QmF0Y2hOb2RlOjE=",
      "name": "Default Batch"
    }
  }
}
```

> But I have a fairly strong fear this will break something downstream,
>   at the level of caching perhaps?
>   Also this does not allow filtering by ID still since filtering depends on
>   `DjangoFilterConnectionField`

## Request

I am stuck at the moment. I have a few questions:

1. Is this an unusual requirement to begin with? Am I asking the wrong
   question when I wish to retain the **ability to filter by pk**
2. Is there a standard pattern to solve this problem?

### Related Issue on Github

> https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/349

### Versions

- graphene-django==2.1.0
- django==1.9.12
- django-filter==1.0.1
- python==2.7.13

Comment: The API always returns the node with the derived Global ID. As a client, if I need to lookup the node, I can utilize this same identifier. Exposing the underlying PK seems unnecessary unless A) there's some other service you're interacting with that uses the PK as a reference or B) the PK is otherwise significant to the client from a business-rules perspective (i.e. the client compares PK values to enforce some business logic). Why do you feel like exposing the PK is necessary?

Comment: Legacy code that is tightly coupled to PKs

Comment: Basically, both A) and B) are true for us.

Comment: website URLs with IDs in are a legitimate use case.

Comment: I considered using graphene, but this is such a strong limitation I'll probably need to move away from the idea

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that you still want the answer or not, but at least let me try to answer to your question. Correct if my understanding is wrong. I just willing to help

Actually `pk` supposed to be `DetailView` not `ListView` that being used with `filter`.

`requirements.txt`

```
graphene-django==2.7.1
django==3.0.1
django-filter==2.2.0
python==3.8.1
```

`models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models

User = get_user_model()


class Objection(models.Model):
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    report = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='objections',
                                   related_query_name='objection')
```

`nodes.py`

```
import django_filters
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from multy_herr.objections.models import Objection


class ObjectionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    pk = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name='pk')

    class Meta:
        model = Objection
        fields = [
            'pk',
        ]


class ObjectionNode(DjangoObjectType):
    pk = graphene.Field(type=graphene.Int, source='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Objection
        fields = [
            'id',
            'pk',
            'detail',
            'hidden',
            'report',
        ]
        filter_fields = {
            'pk': ['exact'],
            'detail': ['icontains', 'istartswith'],
            'created_by__name': ['icontains', ],
            'hidden': ['exact'],
            'report': ['exact'],
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

`queries.py`

```
import graphene
from graphene import relay
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField

from multy_herr.objections.grapheql.nodes import ObjectionNode, ObjectionFilter
from multy_herr.objections.models import Objection


class ObjectionQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    objection = relay.Node.Field(ObjectionNode)
    all_objections = DjangoFilterConnectionField(ObjectionNode,
                                                 filterset_class=ObjectionFilter)

    def resolve_all_objections(self, info, **kwargs):
        if info.context.user.is_authenticated is False:
            return Objection.objects.none()
        return Objection.objects.filter(created_by=info.context.user)
```

I leave comment in `query` here for analogy. With my hackish solution `Insomnia` application will warns me with `Unknown argument pk ...`. But works

`query`

```
query{
#   objection(id: "T2JqZWN0aW9uTm9kZTo1"){
#     id
#     report
#     hidden
#   }
  allObjections(pk: 5){
    edges{
      node{
        id
        pk
        hidden
        report
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`response`

```
{
  "data": {
    "allObjections": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "T2JqZWN0aW9uTm9kZTo1",
            "pk": 5,
            "hidden": false,
            "report": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried solution 2 but with using id as the source instead?

```py
class PKMixin(object):
    pk = graphene.Field(type=graphene.Int, source='id')
```

Also, if you're only looking to fetch a single record, you shouldn't go via a connection field anyway. You should define something like a `batchByPk` field on your schema instead.

A final thing to be aware of, is that at the current time graphene-django's `DjangoFilterConnectionField` isn't implemented in an efficient way, so you may not even want to use it anyway.

Comment: Can you tell me more about how `DjangoFilterConnectionField` is inefficient? Is there documentation or issues on Github I can read to find out more?

Comment: `source='id'` does not help - same error:
>'Meta.fields' contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: pk
This error persists unless an explicit FilterSet is declared with `pk`.

Comment: @rtindru at the moment, all of the connection code in Graphene implements limit/offset pagination rather than true cursor-based pagination, so it doesn't have any of the true benefit of the pattern -- it's just faking it.